# How can you attach to a RecyclerView two LiveData object depending which menu will be click?

Tags: android, performance, android-room, android-livedata

There is a list where every item is shown and you can select favorites from the list with a toggle menu.

There is 2 methods:

```
private void retrieveCodes() {
        mCodeRepository.getAllTask().observe(this.getActivity(), new Observer<List<Code>>() {...
}
private void showFavorites() {
        mCodeRepository.getFavoritesTask().observe(this.getActivity(), new Observer<List<Code>>() {...
}
```

I save - which list is shown - in SharedPreferences.
I have only one ArrayList to hold the item, and I clear it depending which method (all or favorites) is running.
But when I click on the list item's favorite icon, which sets the item as favorite there is two item OnClickListener - (one attached to the list item and onother attached to the favorite icon of the list item), the two Observer item runs separately. How can this done? Should I remove the observer and reattach them one by one?

Comment: Keep a global  `boolean` variable, on menu click (fav. click), change boolean variable & depending on that update the Adapter list.

Comment: Yes, I made this at the moment. But when I tap to show the favorite items, and to show all of them, there will be some confusing behavior: when I tap on a list item's favorite icon to set it favorite, sometimes it just shows the faverot list, but I did not tap to show the favorit list. I don't really know why. First I thought it is because of the Adapters Click fires an event always which notifys the adapter and all of the LiveData fires?

Comment: Ok, I found the bug... I needed to check in the Observer's onChanged method which menu is active and reinit the RecyclerAdapter and RecyclerView